# Are all elements of groups Garside elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid

Here in the definition of [Garside Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garside_element), it seems that if the monoid here is a group, then all its elements are Garside elements simply because all elements are both left and right divisors of any group element and of course the set of all these elements generate the group itself. But is this true?

Comment: Yeah, it's true.

Comment: I do believe it is true, but it is also weird. Why do we talk about Garside Elements of braid groups if Garside elements are the same as elements in any group?

Comment: It can't be because a group with a Garside element has a solvable word problem. I'm just going by what the article says though, so don't quote me on it because I don't know if it's actually true.

Comment: Perhaps we have a wrong definition on Wikipedia. (I remember the former Wikipedian definition of cluster algebra seems to also be flawed so this is not that surprising..)

Comment: All elements of finite groups are Garside elements. See "Braid Groups," by Kassel and Turaev. I think their definition is slightly different from the one on Wikipedia, but I don't have a copy of the book right now.

Comment: The reason we talk about the Garside elements of braid groups is because they are really the Garside elements of the orresponding braid monoid. i.e. the monoid defined by the standard presentationof the braid group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Now I know what the real problem is about...you have answered the question..